# Exercício Linguagem PHP

Tags: php

Alguém pode me ajudar:

Em PHP: 
Crie uma classe que tenha dois métodos; 
O método 1 calcula o módulo da divisão do número de matrícula (número qualquer) por um número inteiro (você decide qual número inteiro utilizar); 
O método 2 irá imprimir na tela o resultado obtido pelo cálculo realizado no método 1.

Comment: Qual sua dúvida? O que você tentou fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Não é o objetivo do site resolver questão e sim tirar dúvidas. Mas ao que parece você é novata então vou responder sua pergunta. Podemos definir essa classe de muitas formas, mas escolhi fazer da forma mais fácil possível. Segue o código:

```
<?php
    class Modulo{

        private $resto;

        public function restoDivisao($matricula, $denominador) {
            $this->resto = $matricula%$denominador;
        }

        public function imprimeResto() {
            echo $this->resto;
        }
    }
?>
```

Aqui definimos a classe que tem apenas um parâmetro, que é o resto da divisão. Ele é um parâmetro privado, ou seja, só pode ser acessado pelos próprios métodos da classe. Para usar essa classe você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$resto = new Modulo;
$resto->restoDivisao(9,4);
$resto->imprimeResto();
```

Primeiro instanciamos a classe, criando um objeto e guardando na variável $resto. Depois chamamos  `métido restoDivisao()`, passando como parâmetros o número da matricula (um número qualquer) e o divisor. Esse método faz o cálculo do resto e guarda no atributo privado. Depois chamamos o método `imprimeResto()` que pega o atributo que setamos no método anterior e imprime na tela.